# Gradient of a function on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

If I have a vector field on a sphere, I can I check that there is no a function that its gradient is the vector field (foe any Riemannian metric)?

Comment: A quick test. If a vector field in a compact manifold has no zeros then it cannot be a gradient (it would vanish at critical points of the potential function). This is also a hint that if this vector is a gradient, you have to look for a function whose critical points are precisely the zeros of the vector field.

Comment: Thanks! and if the vector field has zeros? how can I prove that the field is not a gradient?

Comment: The first Betti number of a sphere (in n>1 dimensions) is zero. So to check if a vector field $\omega$ is a gradient (i.e. if it is exact $\omega=d\Phi$) you only need to compute its exterior differential $d\omega$. If $d\omega=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\omega$ is a gradient.